# How to convert an integer to a string in base 36 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I need to convert an unsigned integer to a string representation with base 36. Before Rust 1.7, it was possible with [`std::fmt::Radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/std/fmt/struct.Radix.html). Is there a way to do that in stable Rust?

Comment: Well yes, same way as before 1.7 - with [char::from_digit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/char/fn.from_digit.html).

Comment: suggest adding code to the question to make it better/easier to answer.